# how to show $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\cos^2(x)}{1+a^x} dx= \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

-Let $a\neq 0$ then  how to show $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\cos^2(x)}{1+a^x}  dx= \frac{\pi}{2}$$

I have tried $a=1$ to get that answer is $\int_{0}^{\pi} \cos^2(x) dx$ and it seems correct. now I can't go on with general answer. I think it may use Feynmans Trick.

Comment: Hint: Do the change of variable $x=-t$ on the integral on $[-\pi,0]$

Comment: Shashi it is not said but i think $a > 0$. You can consider your comment again

Comment: @theweeknd I have deleted my comment. The only thing I can say that it is a wonder the answer does not depend on $a$!

Comment: Shashi - I thought using Feynmans trick to show this, but kellener gave a good comment. Can you show it in another way :)

Comment: There is really no need to show it in another way. Your answer is fine and I don't believe there is one as fine as that and as short as that.

Answer (score 6):

I used Kellener's good comments, $x\to -x$
$$I =\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\cos^2(x)}{1+a^x} dx =\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{a^x\cos^2(x)}{1+a^x} dx $$

therefore on addition, $$2I = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos^2(x)dx = \int_{0}^{\pi} 1+\cos(2x) dx = \pi$$

Again get answer again as $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Thanks a lot to Kellener.

Answer (score 2):

First, let $I$ be your integral. You can use that for all $a >0$
$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\text{d}x}{1+a^{x}}=\pi-\frac{\ln\left(1+a^\pi\right)}{\ln\left(a\right)}-\left(-\pi-\frac{\ln\left(1+a^{-\pi}\right)}{\ln\left(a\right)}\right)=2\pi-\pi=\pi
$$
Then introduce its twin integral $J$ defined by
$$
J=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\sin^2\left(x\right)}{1+a^{x}}\text{d}x
$$
Then
$$
I+J=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\text{d}x}{1+a^{x}}=\pi$$
Now let's go to the original and tricky part,

$$
I-J=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\cos\left(2x\right)}{1+a^{x}}\text{d}x=\int_{-\pi}^{0}\frac{\cos\left(2x\right)}{1+a^{x}}\text{d}x+\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\cos\left(2x\right)}{1+a^{x}}\text{d}x
$$
with $u=-x$ you have $\text{d}x=-\text{d}u$ and
$$
\int_{-\pi}^{0}\frac{\cos\left(2x\right)}{1+a^{x}}\text{d}x=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{a^x\cos(2x)}{a^x+1}\text{d}x$$

summing the two gives you
$$
I-J=\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos\left(2x\right)\text{d}x=0
$$
Hence
$$
I+J=\pi \ \text{ and } I=J
$$
You finally have

> $$
> I=\frac{\pi}{2}
> $$

Comment: in your third to last line I think you meant $I+J=0$, not $J=0$

Comment: Oh yeah thanks, i correct it

Answer (score 1):

for $a\neq 0$ we let  $$I(a) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\cos^2(x)}{1+a^x}  dx\implies I'(a) = -\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{xa^{x-1}\cos^2(x)}{(1+a^x)^2}  dx $$

letting $x= -t$ gives $$I'(a) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{ta^{-t-1}\cos^2(t)}{(1+a^{-t})^2}  dt  = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{ta^{2t}a^{-t-1}\cos^2(t)}{(a^{t}+1)^2}  dt =\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{ta^{t-1}\cos^2(t)}{(a^{t}+1)^2}  dt =-I'(a)$$

> Hence $2I'(a) = 0$ $$ I'(a) = 0\implies I(a) =I(1) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}  \cos^2(x) dx =\frac{\pi}{2}$$